# Exponential iteration into specific range

Tags: c++, math

I need to iterate into specific range with linear and exponential steps. Linear steps is not problem, but with exponential i don't know what's need to nominator.

```
//Linear:
start = 20;
end = 200;
sampleRate = 1000;
duration = 1;
while(1)
{
   delta = (end - start) / (sampleRate * duration);
// 0.18  = (200 - 20)    / (1000       * 1);
   f += delta
   if(f >= end)
      f = start;
}
//Exponential
while(1)
{
   delta = /*???*/ / (sampleRate * duration);
   f += delta
   if(f >= end)
      f = start;
}
```

Thanx!

Comment: does it make sense to calculate delta inside de loop if it does not change? For the exponencial function you can use exp: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/exp/

Comment: _"what's need to nominator"_ -- sorry, I'm having trouble parsing this. What is it supposed to mean?

Comment: @JaMiT, sorry for my English. I put  /*???*/ to my problem.

Comment: @MikhailIvanov Sorry, that does not help as I am still not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. Describing what you want in words is preferred. An example would help. Maybe collaborate with a friend to work on the wording? (A tip to improve your chances of getting a good answer from [ask]: *"If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend to proof-read it for you."*)

Comment: Ok, i'll try to make clear my question.
i'm work over Sine Sweep generator and i want to have generate linear and logarithmic sweep. With linear sweep i don't have problem, because i increase  my frequency on fixed value every sample (sapmleRate * duration in seconds), But with formula exponential growth of frequency i have a problem.

Comment: @MikhailIvanov That's getting closer. Can you write out how you would do a logarithmic sweep by hand, if you did not have a computer to do the grunt work? (Pick a simple example to work through if that helps.) That might be a useful edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

For exponential change, you need to multiply the numerator by some factor in each iteration.

```
//Exponential
range = end - start;
expFactor = 1.5; //Choose this according to your requirement
while(1)
{
   delta = range / (sampleRate * duration);
   f += delta
   if(f >= end)
      f = start;
   range *= expFactor;
}
```

Comment: i need to run my loop exactly (sampleRate * duration) times, but growth with exponential

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found an answer.

First time you want to set a two range. First of is original range in linear scale. Second - range in target logarithmic scale.
For my question:

[start====================end                ]

[firstSample==============sampleRate*Duration]

Then you want to calculate conversation with formulas. I write it on Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/utb5nu1pvq

And my code:

```
SinSweep()
    {

    start=20;
    end=200; 
    sampleRate=1000;
    range=end-start; 
    sampleCount=sampleRate*duration;
    logMax=log10f(end/start);
    currentSample=0;
    f=start;

    While(1){
        switch (type) {
        case Linear:
            f = (((currentSample-1)/sampleCount)*range)+start;
            break;
        case Logarithmic:
            f = start*(powf(10, logMax*(currentSample/sampleCount)));
            break;
            }
    currentSample++;

    if(f >= end){
        f = start;
        currentSample = 0;
        }
    }
}
```